# Differential equation with random variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods

How can I derive analytically or compute numerically the solution to following differential equation

$$ dy/dt = y\cdot X\cdot (y\cdot X - g(y,X))\cdot X $$

where X is a random variable (e.g. from a normal distribution) and g is a known function of y and X, e.g. $g=E[(y\cdot X)^2]$ ?

Comment: Hi is X depending on time , ie a stochastic process itself ?

Comment: Hi TheBridge, yes, X is a stochastic process.

Comment: Hi could you be more specific about g as written it doesn't really make much sense to me.

Comment: g is the expected value of $y\cdot X$, i.e. g(t) = E[(y(t)X(t)]. The problem I try to model arises from learning in neural networks. X is random input to a node and y is the input weight to this node that changes according to the above equation. $y \cdot X$ is then the output activity of the node.

Comment: Hi I think that maybe instead of writing it in differential form, you should start writing it in a evolution form as it seems that time can be taken discrete in your case. Then ifif we can figure things out in this case we should try to give it a meaning in the continuous time framework. Best regards.

Comment: ok, thank you for the suggestion. I'll try to work on the discrete case first and post the results.